# Delete row in a UItable upon selection using right mouse button - Matlab 2020a

Tags: matlab, matlab-app-designer

In this function (app designer) I delete a row in a table upon selection using the left button of the mouse, how can I use the right button or another key+mouse combination for selection instead of the left?

Code:

```
% Cell selection callback: infoTable
        function infoTableCellSelection(app, event)
            indices = event.Indices;
            data = app.infoTable.Data;
            row = indices(:,1);
            figSelect = uifigure;
            figSelect.SelectionType ='alt'; 
            selection = uiconfirm(figSelect,'Delete row?','Confirm Close',...
                        'Icon','question');
            disp(selection); 
            disp(figSelect.SelectionType);
            switch selection
            case 'OK'
                app.infoTable.Data(row,:) = [];
                close(figSelect);
            case 'Cancel'
                close(figSelect);
                return
            end
```

Later in the code:

```
function createComponents(app)
...
    app.infoTable.CellSelectionCallback = createCallbackFcn(app, @infoTableCellSelection, true);
```

Answer (score -1):

Any modifiers keys (i.e. shift, control) that are being pressed when the uitable is selected can be detected through the parent `uifigure` (I'll call it `app.figMain`). The modifiers are returned in a cell array via the undocumented command `modifiers = get(app.figMain,'CurrentModifier')`. You can use an `if` statement that only runs if no key presses are listed in `modifiers`. In other words, the table selection callback only runs for a left-click, but not for shift-click, ctrl-click, etc.

Implementing this in the given code:

```
    function infoTableCellSelection(app, event)
        modifiers = get(app.figMain,'CurrentModifier');
        if isempty(modifiers) % Check that shift-key, ctrl-key, etc. is not pressed
            indices = event.Indices;
            data = app.infoTable.Data;
            row = indices(:,1);
            figSelect = uifigure;
            selection = uiconfirm(figSelect,'Delete row?','Confirm Close',...
                        'Icon','question');
            disp(selection); 
            disp(figSelect.SelectionType);
            switch selection
            case 'OK'
                app.infoTable.Data(row,:) = [];
                close(figSelect);
            case 'Cancel'
                close(figSelect);
                return
            end
        end
    end
```

MATLAB Undocumented describes the `CurrentModifier` command: [CurrentModifier](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog_old/figure-keypress-modifiers)

Comment: I added `figSelect.SelectionType ='alt';`  in the script but it does not work. any idea why?

Comment: `SelectionType` returns a string, so the `==` comparison operator doesn't work (The `=` operator only sets values and can't compare them). You need to use `strcmp` to compare strings. See [strcmp](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html). Also, adding the line by itself doesn't do anything useful. Use `if strcmp(figSelect.SelectionType,'alt')` followed by your code to run the code only if the right-mouse button was clicked.

Comment: I do not wish to compare. My desire is to use the right mouse button to run the `selection` and therefore I need to set it as I did with `figSelect.SelectionType ='alt'; ` but it does not work. Maybe you can add the if command so I can follow

Comment: I updated my answer above. `figSelect.SelectionType` _returns_ what type of mouse click was used; it cannot _set_ what type of click the figure responds to.

Comment: Thank a lot for the help but this does not answer my question. BTW the `uifigure` declaration is inside the loop.

Comment: I somewhat misunderstood your original question (sorry). It turns out that `SelectionType` only registers when blank regions of the figure are clicked. There is a different command (see above) that checks if the shift key is currently pressed when the table selection callback runs. This sorts out left-click from shift+left-click.

Comment: How do I get my equivalent to your `app.figMain`?

Comment: Try `app.infoTable.Parent` or the name of the figure in App Designer that holds the uitable (the default is probably `app.UIFigure`).

Comment: Thanks for the persistence. i changed to app.infoTable.Parent and I get this error `Error using isempty Too many input arguments.`

Comment: I fixed a type in the third line of code. Now it reads `if isempty(modifiers)`.

Comment: It does not work. I think Mathworks will need to have in house solution for this issue